# Open a ported Android app in blackberry 10 using a custom url scheme

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I'm using

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myApp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

to launch myApp when a user click on a myapp://bla url, this is working fine in Android but not when I port my app to BlackBerry (everything else seems to be working fine).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Launcher intents are not supported after the Android port to BlackBerry10:

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html

Comment: Yeah is what I was afraid of... but I'm looking for a way to emulate it.